# Are there any definitive sources for English word forms?

Tags: grammar, resources, conjugation

My interest in English grammar began because of learning about the rules of grammar while learning Latin. In inter-language dictionaries, it's common to mention the declension of nouns, conjugation of verbs, etc.

In English, however, I'm often hard pressed for a source to turn to when I want to know what the past participle of a verb or the comparative of an adjective is. I frequently turn to the Oxford English Dictionary, and it is occasionally useful (there is a nice note about the comparative and superlative of *little*), but it doesn't appear to be at all consistent (there is no mention of the comparative and superlative forms of *stupid*).

Are there better sources for this information?

Comment: No dictionary I know of would waste valuable space giving regular plurals, comparatives, superlatives, etc. And if there was one, I certainly wouldn't buy it. The standard rules are simple enough - just learn them once and assume they apply unless anything says different.

Comment: @FumbleFingers sorry, I was thinking only about online dictionaries, where space isn't really a concern. And what do you do when there is no standard rule? Like for the comparative of a two-syllable adjective? Sure, forming the comparative/superlative has few irregularities, but when the standard rule is '-er/-est for 1 syllable; more/most for 3 or more syllables', the rule itself is an irregularity for two-syllable words.

Comment: Well on that basis you probably don't need any more references. I've got by all my life without conciously knowing that "three-syllable" rule. I doubt I've often transgressed it, but I might have done. You won't, because you know the rule (which is not *two*, it's just *one*. **Optionally replace more/most with er/est if less than three syllables**).

Comment: @rubergly Perhaps you are thinking of a usage dictionary, such as _Merriam-Webster's Dictionary of English Usage_? I don't think it has detailed declension/inflection tables, but it _does_ list irregularities, such as which prepositions collocate with an intransitive verb (do you agree _on_ or agree _about_ something?), and whether phrases like "hone in" are acceptable. Some learner's dictionaries list irregular inflections, too.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, that's the helpfulest comment I see here!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My best recommendation is [Wiktionary.org](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wiktionary%3aMain_Page), which contains forms, pronunciations, even anagrams.

Comment: My main concern is consistency. From your experience, is wiktionary consistent with this info?

Comment: Yes, it is consistent. Additionally, it usually gives links so, if you are unsure, you can verify

Answer (score -1):

Yes, I think there are some reliable dictionaries that help us to know the word's resources, such as my preferred one, [Word Web](http://www.wordwebonline.com/)!

Comment: Can you give us a link to that? It sounds like an on-line resource.